# Updating "about me" field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm having a great deal of difficulty trying to submit a quick form to update a user's "About Me" section. It's an optional field, users can leave it blank if they wish. I can't figure it out!

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    key_expires = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    portfolio_site = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'email', 'username']

class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['about_me', 'portfolio_site']
```

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def update_about(request, user_id):
    # Accquire submitted data and place to "data"
    data = request.POST

    # Isolate submitted data under "id_about_me", and place it to "about_me"
    about_me = data.get('id_about_me')

    new_about = UserProfile(id=request.user.id, about_me=about_me)
    new_about.save()


    return HttpResponse('Great Job!')
```

If I use "user_id=request.user.id", then it says:

```
IntegrityError at /update_about/1/
UNIQUE constraint failed: register_userprofile.user_id
```

If I use "id=request.user.id", then it says:

```
IntegrityError at /update_about/1/
NOT NULL constraint failed: register_userprofile.user_id
```

I can handle other updates just fine, but this one has me stumped!

Comment: are you looking for updating every form field using django forms? how/where are you using django forms to render the profile update form?

Comment: You have a form, but you don't seem to be using it at all in your view.

Comment: Yea about the form, I'd like to update via a popup, right on the page. Single fields at a time actually. Is that possible with forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're creating a new instance of your `UserProfile` model and assigning the same `user_id` to it, leading to the `Unique constraint` error. You should first retrieve your already existing model and modify it like so:

```
new_about = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_request_id)
new_about.about_me = about_me
new_about.save()
```

Tell me if this works. If `user_id` is your auto-primary-key field, though, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck, I'll try it in a moment.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Should be

 new_about = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)


 new_about.about_me = about_me_raw


 new_about.save()

Answer (score 0):

You need to create, or fetch a profile if it already exists:

```
profile,created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
profile.about_me = about_me
profile.save()
```

But why don't you use the form?

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import ProfileForm

@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def update_about(request, user_id):
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
       profile = form.save(commit=False)
       profile.user = request.user
       profile.save()
       return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'update_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Your template just has the normal form rendering logic:

```
<form method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks!, I actually want to update via popup in the page, and not in another page. When updating, single fields at a time. Is that possible with forms?

Comment: @Bob, yes it's possible. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/)